# Track file create/move/write in PHP

Tags: php, progress, flush

I am writing an application to manage files and I would like to know which is the best way to track the write/move and creation process.
I need it to create a visual progress bar.

example:

Using the function rename() I move a file (minimum 600 MB) from a location to another. 
So I know the dimension of the file, maybe I can check for the destination file size every x seconds and  write a progress bar.

This is an idea , but I'm sure there is a better way, hope somene can help me.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You should do all that clientside with something like jQuery file uploader. It's a truly excellent plugin with some great functionality

[get it here](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)